# Use UIViewRepresentable for custom components not working

Tags: swiftui, custom-controls

I have written a lot of components in Swift using UIKit. I'd like to use this custom components with SwiftUI now. I create a struct using UIViewRepresentable:

```
struct MyIcon: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> HUIIconView {
        return HUIIconView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

My HUIIconView is defined like this:

```
@IBDesignable @objc public class HUIIconView: UIView
```

Xcode gives me the following error:

> Type 'MyIcon' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewRepresentable'

This approach works nicely with Apple's own components like *UITextView* but does not work for custom components.
How can I use my own components with SwiftUI?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is (tested with Xcode 11.4)

```
@IBDesignable @objc public class HUIIconView: UIView {

}

struct MyIcon: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> HUIIconView {
        return HUIIconView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: HUIIconView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the error was misleading me. I simply forgot to replace UITextView with HUIIconView in updateUIView().